# Частота повторения букв по шаблону из файла

Tags: java

У меня есть два файла, в одном лежит текс, во втором файле лежат шаблоны.

К примеру слово: Холода.

Шаблон на выборку 'о2', скажет, что в слове должно быть две буквы 'о'.

Я написал код, который работает если шаблон просто 'о', алгоритм пробегается по тексту и находит все буквы 'о'.

Нужно чтобы алгоритм умел работать с любыми шаблонами  вида: буква+количество

Как сделать, чтоб алгоритм понял, что я от него хочу?

```
int count = 0;

try {
    String text = Files.readString(Path.of("Z:/text.txt"));
    String templates = Files.readString(Path.of("Z:/templates.txt"));
    String[] newTemplates = templates.split(" ");


    for (String newTemplate : newTemplates) {
        for (int j = 0; j < text.length(); j++) {
            String letter = String.valueOf(text.charAt(j));
            if (letter.equals(newTemplate)) {
                count++;

            }
        }
        System.out.println(newTemplate + "  " + count);
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Я не понял что вы хотите от алгоритма, поэтому не знаю как подсказать ему, чтобы он понял, что вы от него хотите

Comment: @SergeyZh. Есть текст, есть шаблон, в тексте есть слово, в котором содержится две буквы 'o' , как объяснить алгоритму, что нужно найти кол-во слов с двумя буквами 'о' используя шаблон 'о2')

Comment: То есть задача для конкретного шаблона о2 или надо чтобы алгоритм умел любые шаблоны обрабатывать вида буква+количество?

Comment: @SergeyZh. Ага, буква + кол-во, 'o2' это для примера)

Comment: Шаблон гарантированно состоит из одной буквы и одного числа? Или может быть несколько букв и т.д.? Нужно искать именно по словам?

Comment: @WarLikeLaux может быть несколько букв, а1б2 и тд, да есть набор слов(текст)

Comment: Вы запустили моё решение, оно работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
for (String newTemplate : newTemplates) {
    count = 0;
    String charTemplate = newTemlate.substring(0, 1);
    int countTemplate = Integer.parseInt(newTemplate.substring(1));
    for (String word : text.split(" ")) {
        if (word.split(charTemplate).length - 1 == countTemplate) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(newTemplate + "  " + count);
}
```

Замените цикл, который написан у вас на этот, должно работать. Шаблоны в файле должны идти через пробел: `о1 а3 c22 b4` и так далее.

Comment: Спасибо, протестирую ,как будет доступ к компу, а если я задам последовательность абв и если в слове есть эти буквы подряд, то увеличит счетчик, такое сработает?

Comment: Нет, я конкретно на одну букву делал, шаблон же буква+число, но число любое даже из нескольких знаков пойдёт

Comment: Формат а1б2 не работает?

Comment: Работает, только надо шаблоны через пробел перечислять а1 б2

Comment: В вашем же примере было именно так: String[] newTemplates = templates.split(" ");

Comment: Это я пытался как-то это реализовать, сплит использовал, чтоб каждый фильтр был под своим индексом в массиве

Comment: Ну в общем как-то так, шаблоны через пробел, каждый шаблон буква + число. Должно работать, проверяйте.